# When does a duplicant go by a wash basin and not wash their hands?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

Basically, I've noticed a few times a duplicant going by a wash basin and not washing their hands. That can be the case, obviously, if the basin is out of order — but I've seen it happen on other occasions.

Is this maybe a known bug (since the game's still in early access), or are there certain reasons why a duplicant might not wash their hands?

What are all the reasons why a duplicant might go by a basin and not wash their hands?

Comment: Just checking the obvious - is the basin set to only wash hands in one direction?

Comment: Even if it is, they sometimes go by the basin in _that_ direction and still don't wash their hands.

Comment: How busy is the area? I'm not sure if this changed, but when I played two versions ago dupes wouldn't use the basin if someone else had reserved it.

Comment: _Reserved_ it? Huh... I know that if is _being used_ they won't be able to use it, and they don't queue up or anything. Didn't know it got reserved.

Comment: I assume, the Dupes only wash hands which are dirty or infected?

Comment: I'm beginning to notice a pattern that seems to suggest that's the case, yeah, @PeterCo. The purpose of the question is to try to get a list of all the reasons why they might not wash their hands, though, not to try to figure out why _my_ duplicants didn't wash their hands _in a particular incident_ :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit of an older thread, but I just had this problem, and I was trying for a while to get my dupe to wash his hands when passing by the wash basin. I tried making it bi-directional, I tried "Move to" several times, and nothing. I was just about to restart the game when I noticed something, the basin tubes on the side - where you can see the blue (clean) and green (dirty) water, they were empty.

Should look like this:

[image]

But instead looked like this:

[image]

So clicking on the properties of the basin, I looked at the "Contents" and found this:

[image]

"Contents None"

I then realized that I had a priority of 5 on the basins, so they hadn't added water to them. I upped it to 9, and immediately someone went and got water, now I see this:

[image]

And then my dupe immediately washed his hands as he passed by the basin.  It didn't say it needed any materials (much like a research station says it's waiting on water or dirt, or an oxydizer waits on algae) so I didn't realize they were dry.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the cause is that some other dupe is already using the sink/wash-basin. You should put in one sink per every toilet and set them all to be used only on one direction. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if the toilet is to the right, and the basin is right next to it to the left, they just ignore the basin completely. So I solved it two ways: one is to put the toilet to the left, and the basin to the right, or to have some space between the two.